# Remove Lines with Less than X number of letters Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How do I remove lines with less than X number of letters/numbers?

I see the options to replace words, but that's about it. I've done some Google searches and I have not been able to find this question answered.

Answer (score 10):

Use the replace function and check "Regular expression" in the fieldset 'Search mode'. Find the following:

```
^.{0,5}$
```

The above snippet matches lines with 5 or less characters. Replace with nothing.

Comment: Also, make sure the match new line checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to contribute to this... Replace with Regexp ON, the below with nothing.

```
^.{200,9999999999999}$
```

Would remove lines that are **longer** than 200 chars. Definitely, not the best or most polite way of doing this, but it works :$

Comment: Can you add a sentence explaining how to use this?  Thanks.

Comment: `.{20,}` is better.