# Remove lines with less than X number of letters from Microsoft Word (2016 or higher)?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, find-and-replace

I'm using MS office 365. I have a big MS word document containing more than 10000 lines.

The document has some meaningless lines that contain meaningless alphabet letters, unknown Asian letters, symbols, and numbers, and the number of these characters of those "meaningless lines" are usually less than 10. In other words, my document has some lines of less than 10 characters (letters, Asian letters, symbols, and numbers).

I want to remove these lines that only contain 10 or fewer characters.

It found that Notepad++ can do this
[Remove Lines with Less than X number of letters Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/746625/remove-lines-with-less-than-x-number-of-letters-notepad)

But when I attempt to use find and replace similar regular expressions from MS Word. But they are not working. I tried to search for ^.{0,10}$, then MS word says

```
^. is not a valid special character for the Find What box.
```

So, I tried to search for ^p.[0,10]$ and ^l.[0,10]$ then the MS word can't find any occurrence.

I tried Wildcards, but in this case, the MS word says ^p (or ^) is not a valid special character or is not supported when using Wildcards.

So, I'm not sure if I can search for such occurrences.

Do I need to write a macro for this feature? I know how to delete the entire line containing specific string using Macro, such as:
https://word.tips.net/T003838_Finding_and_Deleting_Rows.html

But I hope to delete the line with less than X number of characters without checking one by one. I have 10000 lines and I cannot check all occurrences... Can we create a Macro to count the number of characters per line and use that as a condition to delete or not and go to the next line?